# if can? does not hide links on show.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have just installed cancan and I have run into a quick, small issue. I should be able to use if_can? to apply action to hide links. This is so only the information that was created by user can of course view the edit/delete links.

I haven't been able to find someone else who has had the same problem. If someone could take a look and help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

show.html:

```
<div id="photos">
    <% for photo in @gallery.photos %>
    <div class="photo">
        <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        <div class="name"><%= photo.name %></div>
        <div class="actions">
            <% if can? :update, @photo %>
            <%= link_to "edit", edit_photo_path(photo) %> |
            <% end %>
            <% if can? :remove, @photo %>
            <%= link_to "remove", photo, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Add a Photo", new_photo_path(:gallery_id => @gallery) %>
|
  <%= link_to "Remove Gallery", @gallery, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> |
  <%= link_to "View Galleries", galleries_path %>
</p>
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all 
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you entered `load_and_authorize_resource` into controller

Comment: In your photos controller do you have ```authorize_resource```?  Also, the only thing I am seeing in your ability class is that all users can read all.

Comment: I just added it, made no difference. class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

Comment: To me it looks like it isn't the galleries controller where you want it.  The reason why is because you are trying to prevent the removal of photo.  If you put it in the galleries controller you are requiring authorization for gallery object not the photo object.

Comment: At the end of the day what I am trying to do is prevent non-content creators from editing/deleting photos & galleries. Then also prevent others users from editing/deleting someone else profile. However atm I am just trying to do the photo part.

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` has nothing to do with this problem. That's just for locking out controller actions, in this instance he's just looking to authorize a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, each controller must be authorized.  The easiest way to do this is to start at photo's and make sure that it cannot be deleted.  You will need something like:

```
can :delete, Photo do |photo|
  question.try(:user) == user
end
```

in your ability.rb.  In your photo's controller you will need to put in either `load_and_authorize_resource` or `authorize_resource`.

Then in your view you want `<%if can :remove, photo %>` not `<%if can :remove, @photo>`.  It seems odd to me you are trying to use `@photo` when you have `<for photo in @gallery.photos %>`

Comment: I understand what that methods does. However for now I was trying to hide the "add a photo" and "remove gallery" links. I am following the railscast #192. And it says to use <% if can? to hide the links. But that is not working. I will need your method at some point, but not atm.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I believe you don't want to use ```@photo```, but rather ```photo```.

Answer (score 0):

i also has passed through this problem. solution is simple in Ability.rb class do something as follows

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.role == "admin"
    can :update, Photo, :user_id => user.id
  end 
end
```

then in index.html.erb do something as follows

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
 <%if can? :update, photo %>
  <!-- hide your links and buttons here-->
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Note: in "<%if can? :update, photo %>" write "photo" instead of "Photo" or "@photo". because here photo is a veriable which will iterate through out the loop.